# Why is the Django serializer.data step slow?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am doing a GET request to return around 100,000 objects from my Django rest framework API. The request is somewhat slow to complete (nearly 2 seconds) and upon further inspection, the slow part is storing the result of `serializer.data`.

The total response size is <5MB so I would expect the response time to be much quicker than this. From reading various articles online, most "Django slowness problems" seem to stem from the N+1 problem which can easily be solved with `prefetch_related` but this doesn't seem to be relevant to my problem as my model has no foreign key.

I've used `django-extensions`'s `runserver --print-sql` to see what queries Django is doing. But when I time the individual segments (as shown in the code block below) the actual query and serialization steps are almost instant. Indeed, the query that `django-extensions` shows is sensible.

I also looked at the source for [Django's serializers](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L248) but I'm still none the wiser as to why the `.data` step might take so long.

The GET request in question (including timing statements) is as follows:

```
class ExampleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        start_time = time.time()
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        query_time = time.time() - start_time
        print('Query time: {}'.format(query_time))
        start_time = time.time()
        serializer = ExampleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        serialization_time = time.time() - start_time
        print('Serialization time: {}'.format(serialization_time))
        start_time = time.time()
        to_return = serializer.data
        serializer_data_time = time.time() - start_time
        print('Serialization data time: {}'.format(serializer_data_time))
        return Response(to_return)
```

With a the following serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'
```

And the following model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

The output of running this GET request is as follows:

```
Query time: 0.0
Serialization time: 0.0
Serialization data time: 1.8892838954925537
```

I'm guessing that this might just be something which can't actually be sped up as 100,000 objects is maybe a lot to be converted from a ListSerializer to a ReturnList in the `.data` step. I just want confirmation that this can't be optimised in any way before moving on.

Comment: you are trying to serialize now 100,000 objects ?

Comment: You should change `queryset = Example.objects.all()` to `queryset = list(Example.objects.all())` to time the database query.

Comment: A. J. is right, however, i had also issues on the serializer.data taking a very long time (after making sure the queryset was fetched) when searching i found https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow maybe it can help you.